# Chinese power supply schematics/components

Tags: power-supply, schematics

I have a chinese power supply which i brought from a garage sale which has some problems. I opened the case and I concluded that some resistors and capacitors are burned. I would like to repair this power supply to use it for small electronic projects at home (60W, 12V, 5A - these are the written ratings).

I would be very happy if somebody could help me somehow to solve this. I just need to know the values of the resistors (for capacitors is easy) and, of course, some guidelines and tips for replacing them.

I attached some photos, to see what I'm talking about.

Have a nice day ! :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: best case is you can salvage some parts with no experience

Comment: Realistically, you appear to value a cheap broken piece of 2nd hand junk that might possibly electrocute  you or your family more than either your time fixing it, or your health. Throw it in the garbage but only if it is marked as being disposable this way else spend some more money and time taking it to where it can be properly recycled as junk.

Comment: @Andy , you're right, the problem is bigger than i thought. I'll go for a new one ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a complete correct answer to this is difficult. The best you can do is look for the UC2384AN application note and find out and understand how such a system is configured. Then try also to unsolder the burned parts carefully and measure them if possible. Most probably the component (transistor) under te heatsink has a short circuit.
Next you have BD1 four diodes in a bridge, This is the incomming rectifier after the filter. After taking out the switching transistor and verifying the big capacitors (they seem to bulge and need replacement. Any bulging capacitor need to repaced anyhow) you should be able to connect the mains. (Carefull for you health) You should then measure mains voltage *1.4. over the capacitors.
Further help is difficult without a schematic. So I suggest you make one and mention the parts and values found and go from there. If things become really difficult show the schematic and we might be able to help more.

Here is the link: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua143/slua143.pdf

Comment: ...and the low voltage filter caps (to the right of the transformer) are bulging, so they need replacing.

Comment: @SteveG: added to my explanation. From the looks at the position they seem to be primairy caps and therefore high voltage.

Comment: Looking further made me to leave it like this and go for a new one. There are more components broken and it takes too much time and money to fix it. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Anyway it is most probably also the safest way.